# Explicitly set the font to be used for recognition by Tesseract-OCR

Tags: fonts, ocr, tesseract

I have documents which use only one font throughout the document. Different documents might have different fonts, but I know which document uses which font.

Is there an option to explicitly tell Tesseract-OCR which font to use during recognition for a given image?

Comment: To help debugging this, you can set `tessedit_debug_fonts` to 1 in order to determine how & what font tesseract identify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't think Tesseract supports such an option. What you can do is to train for one specific font and then specify that traineddata during recognition of your documents.